# How can I refresh for Ribbon UI at any time?

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon

I create a MFC SDI Application.

The application has CMFCRibbonEdit UI that refresh by constant rate.

But, I can't do my constant rate refresh by ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI.

I look like the following.

- moving a cursor on ribbon : refresh by 100ms
- oher : refresh by 1000ms

How can I refresh the UI by my rate (100ms) ?

[image]

Sample Code:

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    ....
    m_wndRibbonBar.Create(this);
    m_wndRibbonBar.LoadFromResource(IDR_RIBBON);

    CMFCRibbonCategory* pCategoryTest = m_wndRibbonBar.AddCategory(L"TEST CAT", IDB_WRITESMALL, IDB_WRITELARGE);
    CMFCRibbonPanel* pPanelTest =  pCategoryTest->AddPanel(L"Test Panel");
    pEdit_ = new CMFCRibbonEdit(ID_EDIT_1, 120, L"test");
    pPanelTest->Add(pEdit_);
    ....

    // data refresh by constant rate (100ms)
    worker_ = std::thread([&] {
        while (1)
        {
            count_ += 0.1f;
            Sleep(100);
        }
    });
    ....
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWndEx)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_SETFOCUS()
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_EDIT_1, &CMainFrame::UpdateCommandUI)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMainFrame::UpdateCommandUI(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
    if (pCmdUI->m_nID == ID_EDIT_1)
    {
        CString str;
        str.Format(L"%f", count_);
        pEdit_->SetEditText(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Set up a timer ([CWnd::SetTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#settimer)) and update the UI element(s) in the timer callback. Optionally adjust the timer in the timer callback when it starts to drift and you need a more steady update rate.

Comment: OK. I try it. Thank you, IInspectable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success!

Thank you, IInspectable!

```
CMainFrame::~CMainFrame()
{
    //KillTimer(TEST_TIMER_ID);
}

int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    ....
    // Create CMFCRibbonEdit
    ....
    // Delete worker thread
    //worker_ = std::thread([&] {
    ....

    // Setup Timer by 100ms
    SetTimer(TEST_TIMER_ID, 100, NULL);

    return 0;
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWndEx)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_SETFOCUS()
    ON_WM_TIMER()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMainFrame::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    if (nIDEvent == TEST_TIMER_ID)
    {
        count_ += 0.1f;
        CString str;
        str.Format(L"%f", count_);
        pEdit_->SetEditText(str);
    }

    CFrameWndEx::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

Comment: `KillTimer` is not doing anything because by that time the window handle is destroyed, and the timers are automatically destroyed by OS. You can skip `KillTimer` if the timer is required throughout the process.